# Iterate over array in async promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, bluebird

I´m working with node/ express, mysql and bluebird.

I´m using Promises to make an async database call, which is working so far. But now I want to iterate over the result (array) and call a function for calculation purpose.

My Code is separated into a Controller class, which handles the `get/ post` request. In the middle a service class for business logic, which talks to a database class which queries in the database.

For now I will just show my service class, because everything else is working perfectly, I just don´t know how to run over the result array and call function, which returns a daterange.

```
'use strict';

var departmentDatabase = require('../database/department');
var moment = require('moment');

class DepartmentService {
    constructor() {
    }

    getVacation(departmentID) {
        return departmentDatabase.getVacation(departmentID).then(function (result) {

            //Without promises I did this, which worked.
            //for(var i = 0; result.length > i; i++){
            // var dateRange = this.getDateRange(new Date(result[i].dateFrom), new Date(result[i].dateTo));
            //console.log(dateRange);
            //}
            return result;

        })

        //If I do it static, the dateRange function is successfully called
        //But here I don´t know how to do it for the entire array.
        //Also I don´t know, how to correctly get the result dateRange()
        .then(result => this.dateRange(result[0].dateFrom, result[0].dateTo))
        //.then() Here I would need an array of all dateRanges
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    getDateRange(startDate, stopDate) {
        console.log("inDateRange");
        console.log(startDate + stopDate);

        var dateArray = [];
        var currentDate = moment(startDate);
        while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
            dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
            currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
        }

        return dateArray;
    }
}

module.exports = new DepartmentService();
```

Hope someone can give me an example on how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new code, you're only handling the first result. You probably want `map`:

```
.then(result => result.map(entry => this.dateRange(entry.dateFrom, entry.dateTo)))
```

So in context with the old code removed:

```
getVacation(departmentID) {
    return departmentDatabase.getVacation(departmentID)
    .then(result => result.map(entry => this.dateRange(entry.dateFrom, entry.dateTo)))
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // WARNING - This `catch` handler converts the failure to a
        //           resolution with the value `undefined`!
    });
}
```

---

Note the warning in the above. If you want to propagate the error, you need to do that explicitly:

```
.catch(err => {
    // ...do something with it...
    // If you want to propagate it:
    return Promise.reject(err);
    // Or you can do:
    // throw err;
});
```

Comment: Wow, perfect! This was what I needed.